# Received doesn't get triggered

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq

I have shared library as Bus, and I am trying to recieve messages from rabbitmq but `ConsumerOnReceived` never get triggered.

```
namespace Bus
{
    public class MessageListener
    {

    private static IConnection _connection;
    private static IModel _channel;

    public void Start(string hostName, int port, string queueName)
    {
        var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = hostName, Port = port };
        using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
        {
            channel.QueueDeclare(queue: queueName,
                                 durable: false,
                                 exclusive: false,
                                 autoDelete: false,
                                 arguments: null);

            var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
            consumer.Received += ConsumerOnReceived;

            channel.BasicConsume(queue: queueName,
                                 noAck: true,
                                 consumer: consumer);
        }
    }

    public static void Stop()
    {
        _channel.Close(200, "Goodbye");
        _connection.Close();
    }

    public virtual void ConsumerOnReceived(object sender, BasicDeliverEventArgs ea)
    {
        var body = ea.Body;
        var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
    }
}

public static class MessageSender
{
    public static void Send(string hostName, int port, string queueName, string message)
    {
        var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = hostName, Port = port };
        using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
        {
            channel.QueueDeclare(queue: queueName, durable: false, exclusive: false, autoDelete: false, arguments: null);

            var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message.ToString());

            channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "", routingKey: queueName, basicProperties: null, body: body);
        }
    }
}

}
```

Core

```
namespace Core
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new MessageListener().Start("localhost", 5672, "MakePayment");

            Console.WriteLine("Core Service");
            string line = Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
}

namespace Core
{
    public class MessageListener : Bus.MessageListener
    {
        public override void ConsumerOnReceived(object sender, BasicDeliverEventArgs ea)
        {
            var body = ea.Body;
            var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here

```
channel.BasicConsume(queue: queueName, noAck: true, consumer: consumer);
```

However, `BasicConsume` is not a blocking method therefore when you call `Start` you create a connection and a channel but then it gets disposed immediately.

The following is **NOT** a solution but you can confirm by doing the following:

```
channel.BasicConsume(queue: queueName, noAck: true, consumer: consumer);
Console.ReadKey();//←Added Line
```

Your program will work this way.

This is my proposed solution. Please take notice that `_channel.BasicConsume(queue: queueName, noAck: true, consumer: consumer);` will start on another thread so you do not need to use `while(...)`

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using RabbitMQ.Client;
using RabbitMQ.Client.Events;

namespace Bus {

    public abstract class BaseMessageListener {
        private static IModel _channel;
        private static IConnection _connection;

        public abstract void ConsumerOnReceived(object sender, BasicDeliverEventArgs ea);

        public void Start(string hostName, int port, string queueName) {
            var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = hostName, Port = port };
            _connection = factory.CreateConnection();
            _channel = _connection.CreateModel();
            _channel.QueueDeclare(queue: queueName, durable: false, exclusive: false, autoDelete: false);
            var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(_channel);
            consumer.Received += ConsumerOnReceived;
            _channel.BasicConsume(queue: queueName, noAck: true, consumer: consumer);//This will start another thread!
        }

        public void Stop() {
            _channel.Close(200, "Goodbye");
            _connection.Close();
        }
    }
}

namespace StackOverfFLow.RabbitMQSolution {

    using Bus;

    public class MessageListener : BaseMessageListener {

        public override void ConsumerOnReceived(object sender, BasicDeliverEventArgs ea) {
            var body = ea.Body;
            var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
            Console.WriteLine(message);
        }
    }

    internal class Program {

        private static void Main(string[] args) {
            var listener = new MessageListener();
            listener.Start("localhost", 5672, "MakePayment");
            Console.WriteLine("Core Service Started!");
            Console.ReadKey();
            listener.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works indeed but is there a better practise then ReadKey to handle this?

Comment: @Mert, I am not exactly sure where you put  `while (_channel.IsOpen) { }` but if you put it after `channel.BasicConsume(queue: queueName, noAck: true, consumer: consumer);` this line; I do not think you need that one. Please see my updated answer.